# Is Step 7 v5.5 compatible with v5.4?

Tags: logic, plc

Does anyone know if a project that was originally created in step 7 v.5.4, then opened, edited, and saved in 5.5, can then be reopened in 5.4 again?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be re-opened if it was saved in a later version.

Comment: To answer my own question, the answer is yes. If the file was originally created in 5.4, then edited and saved in 5.5, it CAN be reopened in 5.4 and edited. I have physically confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you open project with older version, but you can do it.

You may run into some anomalies when using project with different Step 7 versions. But I have not run into anything serious, yet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30844665)